# how to find feature specific threshold in binary classification problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, random-forest, xgboost

I am working on a binary classification problem. Due to client compliance, I am unable to share the data but I will try my best to give an intuition.

The goal is to predict if a person "likes the movie" or "Doesn't like the movie". There are features like age, gender, and movie length along with survey rating data like - Online booking(1-5), cleanliness in movie hall (1-5), etc.

**I wish to evaluate the threshold value below which a "male" tend to say he "doesn't like the movie"**

Can someone help me understand how to find it.

[image: Sample data preview]

Comment: Thanks for responding Golden. No, I have simply used XGB classifier on it.

Comment: Thanks for this but is there any simpler way - which is also easy to understand for the client?

Comment: impossible to know

Comment: the dataset will cluster around cleaniness and length of movie as the determinant for like or dislike.  you will probably find a few clusters that support this observation.  there may be a correlation between age and length of the movie and like.  I suggest you do more feature engineering